# Get primary key of relationship record with ObjectContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, audit

I try to use `ChangeTracker` from EF to do audit and save all changes in database (add + update).

So with `ChangeTracker` I will able to get all changed tables, and all values for each. But I also need of the ID of new records in new tables.

Some of them are relationship, and when I try to get the values with `EntityKey`, the primary key is 0

```
private object GetPrimaryKeyValue(DbEntityEntry entry)
{
    var objectStateEntry = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(entry.Entity);
    return objectStateEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues[0].Value;    
}
```

Someone knows, if I'm on the wrong way and if it's possible to get the primary key of related entity ?

Thanks !

Comment: I think you need to check your database table.  If it is a primary key, it cannot be null (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876785/sql-server-cant-insert-null-into-primary-key-field).

Comment: In fact, I said something wrong, it's not null but 0. The primary key is an autoincremented field in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get 0 (that is default(int)) because autoincremented (identity) columns get populated only after save is done (i.e. `dbContext.SaveChanges` has finalized successfully). Try reading the value after `SaveChanges()` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435462/get-auto-identity-key-after-insert-via-ef).

It looks like a way to catch newly added values, you must override SaveChanges and get generated values yourself like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20007736/2780791).

Comment: Yes, but what I want to do is to save into another table all new added values, for that I retrieves all them with ChangeTracker of EF. When it concerns a update of existing data, it's not a problem, but in this case it's for new rows and the primary key is 0

Comment: I have put an extra reference in my answer.

Comment: Just a small note: As I do not like triggers, I favor .NET solutions. However, keep in mind that triggers might be more suitable if table data can be changed by other application than your own.

Comment: Ok Alexei, your advice and references don't help me because I had the same result, **0** for the primary key. If I do my audit after calling `SaveChanges()`, I lose the `EntityState` value (added in this case) but if check the state `Unchanged` my new added object is there with all values and so with the **ID**. Do you think is right to use the state unchanged after calling `SaveChanges()` for new added object ?