# Change/Status tracking in entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

My question relates to overall design within entity framework 6. My model has an entity type called *Person*. Each person consists of multiple values, some of which it is important that i track the previous values of these properties. An example of that includes *Last Interaction Date* and *Status*

The model currently has a separate entity for each property i wish to track historical status on in this case Person_Status and Person_lastInteraction; the relationship is created with a 1 to many relation.

I extend the Person partial class to allow methods for updating the these tracked properties.

....There has to be a better way!

My Concerns:

1. Every time i want to track a different property i have to create a new entity just for tracking those particular property changes, requiring DB changes
2. Because EF still exposes the property its possible someone could change the person status without using the methods added to the class.
3. I'm re-writing a lot of the same exact code to do essentially the same thing

Has anyone encountered a situation as such, what did you do?

Comment: You're probably looking for an approach like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17904631/861716).

Comment: @GertArnold - Very helpful that was the pattern i was after...