# EF6: Why Does Count return 0 but Find return an element?

Tags: entity-framework

In this code

```
using (var db = new DbPerson())
{
    var b = db.People.Create();
    b.Name = "Homer";

    db.People.Add( b );

    Console.WriteLine( "Count: {0}", db.People.Count() );

    foreach (var bb in db.People)
        Console.WriteLine( bb.Name );

    var fb = db.People.Find( b.Id ); // Id is a GUID generated in the Person ctor
                                     //  NOT a DB-generated Identity.
    Console.WriteLine( "Found: {0}", fb != null );

    db.SaveChanges();

    Console.WriteLine( "Count: {0}", db.People.Count() );
}
```

the output looks like this:

```
Count: 0
Found: True
Count: 1
```

I have seen other posts about Count not being updated until `SaveChanges` is called. OK, so this is the "way it works".

My question is specifically this: Why does `Find` return an object from `db.People` when `Count()` returns 0 and the enumerator returns no elements? Shouldn't `Find` and `Count()` act similarly, waiting for `SaveChanges` before returning Entities that are in the "Added" state?

What is the reasoning for this? I ask because I am writing a light-weight non-SQL provider that needs to mirror the actions of EF as nearly as possible. I can't figure out what logic causes `Find` to return an Added element that `Count()` and `GetEnumerator()` doesn't. I need to address these situations.

Answer (score 1):

`Find()` has a special quality: it will first look into the DbContext's entities that have been newly added but not yet flushed to the database (e.g.: entities with `EntityState.Added`).

`Count()` and the enumerator will instead look at the database, which obviously doesn't have anything yet until you call `SaveChanges()`.

[Background info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj573936.aspx)

Comment: I completely understand this. My question is Why, and where else do I need to know that the context's newly added entities are searched/included and where are they not?

Comment: Each time you are getting unexpected results, I assume? For example this was also explained in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx): "*If an entity with the given primary key values exists in the context, then it is returned immediately without making a request to the store.*"

Comment: After reading the docs on every method on `DbSet<>`, as well as testing things such as using `Queryable.FirstOrDefaulit` on a `DbSet`, I think that's the answer- The Find method is the only place where it states explicitly that the return values are from the context, not the database. `FirstOrDefault` will not "find" the entity until after the Save Changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask *why* it is implemented like this: `Find` is supposed to allow you to access tracked entities by ID that are not in the database. `Find` is a rather special purpose method. Maybe it allows to retrieve deleted entities as well, the docs don't say. [There are other APIs for reaching into the pool of tracked entities as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122461/get-all-tracked-entities-from-a-dbcontext)

Usually it is a sign of bad use of EF (or a sign of a hack) if you need to mess with that.

NHibernate had a really useful `Find`: It allowed you to get an entity *without* going to the database. It returns a proxy. That way you always could pass around entity objects and almost never IDs. A nice abstraction. This is not possible with EF. `Find` goes to the database.

Comment: I just tested it- An entity that has been Removed (before SaveChanges, in the "Deleted" state) will also be returned by Find.

Comment: Btw, NHibernate was nice in another regard. It automatically saved all changes before each query. That way the database was always in sync and it was hard to tell the difference between context results and db results. The motto of NHibernate was persistence ignorance.